# Как хранить данные в MONGO DB?

Tags: mongodb

Добрый день. Изучаю mongodb и хочу построить небольшую модель бд для сайта с блогами.
Как известно в mongodb вместо таблиц коллекции, а вместо записей документы.
У меня имеются 2 документа (сущности): User (id, nikname) и Publication(id, title, text..и др. поля но это неважно). В реляционной бд в таблице Publication имелся бы user_id и 
Это означало бы что у пользователя могут быть множество публикаций.

В монго, предполагаю, будет так:

**Пример1**

```
User 
{
  id: "123456",
  nikname: "cool guy",
  publications: [   
        {
            id: "some id1",
            title: "some title111",
            text: "bla bla bla",
            // any fields
        },
        {
            id: "some id2",
            title: "some title222",
            text: "bla bla bla",
            // any fields
        },
        ....
    ]
}
Publication 
{
    id: "some id",
    title: "some title",
    text: "bla bla bla",
    // any fields       
}
```

То есть каждый юзер имеет свой собственный массив публикаций.

**Так вот вопрос:** Правильный ли это подход? 
Потому что один документ в этот случае невероятно разбухнет. Что если у одного юзера будет 1000 публикаций? 
Более того, если каждый пользователь имеет свои пуликации "в себе", то зачем хранить "таблицу" (в монго, коллекцию) публикаций отдельно ВНЕ юзера?

Думал также о варианте с хранением массива id-шников внутри user-а.

Но как мне кажется, самый простой и лучший вариант - когда в публикациях есть USER_ID: 
**Пример2**

```
User 
{
  id: "123456",
  nikname: "cool guy"
}

Publication 1
{
    id: "some id",
    title: "some title",
    text: "bla bla bla",
    // any fields   

    USER_ID: 123456 
}



Publication 2
{
    id: "some id",
    title: "some title",
    text: "bla bla bla",
    // any fields

    USER_ID: 123456     
}
```

Но в этом случае это ничем не отличается от "старого" реляционного подхода...

Какой из вариантов лучше всего? Может есть и другие варианты, которые я упускаю.
        Нормально ли если я буду в mongo использовать вариант из **Примера2** ?

Вообщем хотелось бы услышать мнению опытных.

---

larrymacbarry, не хватает репутации чтобы ответить на ваш ответ. Вопрос принадлежит мне.

Да, можно хранить идентификаторы публикаций в user.

Но что если нам понадобиться по записи определить какому пользователю она принадлежит? В этом случае, чтобы найти автора (или любую информацию связанную с ним) публикации нам придется пройтись по всем publications всех авторов (пользователей) в поиске нужного publicId.

Поэтому надо хранить userId в самой публикации.
Однако, если есть userId в публикации тогда теряется смысл в хранении такого рода:

```
publications: ["5a4385f6acd28e1ed297f8fa", "5a425c7af58ad94c293979a3", ...]
```

Comment: "Но в этом случае это ничем не отличается от "старого" реляционного подхода..." - в случае с монго - у Вас скорость чтения-записи будет в несколько раз выше, при аналогичном подходе с мускулом

Comment: разница в том что mongo горизонтально расширяем.

Comment: У вас данные строго реляционные. На надо использовать документарную БД для хранения реляционных данных. Документарные БД предназначены для других задач. https://habrahabr.ru/post/231213/

Comment: larrymacbarry, не хватает репутации чтобы ответить на ваш ответ. Вопрос принадлежит мне. Да, можно хранить идентификаторы публикаций в user. Но что если нам понадобиться по записи определить какому пользователю она принадлежит? В этом случае, чтобы найти автора (или любую информацию связанную с ним) публикации нам придется пройтись по всем publications всех авторов (пользователей) в поиске нужного publicId. Поэтому надо хранить userId в самой публикации.
Однако, если есть userId в публикации тогда теряется смысл в хранении такого рода: publications: ["5a4385f6acd28e1ed297f8fa", "5a425c7af58ad9

Comment: "Вопрос принадлежит мне." - Нет, не вам, вопрос был создан с другого аккаунта. Автор вопроса может комментировать всё в своём вопросе и без репутации.

Comment: оставил запрос на слияние аккаунтов

Comment: Лично я бы хранил (и храню) в монге ссылки на id избыточно: и в users и в publications на всякий пожарный. Для пользователя так проще было б выводить статистику и тд. А в постах конечно же необходимо хранить id автора, и у вас оно как раз есть USER_ID: 123456

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/224453)

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/224453)

Answer (score 1):

Нет, достаточно хранить id записей пользователя. Так же для пользователей и для записей можно хранить аватарки и изображения, записывая лишь url изображения в базе данных.

```
  User 
    {
      id: "123456",
      nikname: "cool guy",
      publications: [   
            "5a4385f6acd28e1ed297f8fa", "5a425c7af58ad94c293979a3", ...
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что здесь лучше в публикации сохранять и ID пользователя и его ник. Тогда наиболее частая операция - отображение записи блога будет делаться наиболее просто и быстро.

Answer (score 0):

Создаешь 2 модельки:
1)

```
var User = mongoose.Schema({
    email: {type: String, unique: true},
   });



var Vacancy = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    salary: Number,
    author_id: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    date: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
```

Тут я сохраняю ID юзера который запостил вакансию